# Ruby: Parsing Json statements that use x[{a:b, c:d}]

Tags: json, ruby

I'm parsing a JSON document like

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "tick": {
    "id": 101006380508,
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "10100638050832281590023",
        "amount": 0.2251,
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am currently doing:

```
data = JSON.parse(response.read_body)
data["tick"]["data"]["amount"]
```

and getting an error

> Error: []': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)

My objective is the get the **amount**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's array that contains one hash, so you can get it as

```
data["tick"]["data"].first["amount"] # => 0.2251
```